# Creating a bar chart that sums data from a txt file

Tags: python-2.7

So, im trying to create a bar chart that takes data from a txt file that has 3 rows. The idea is for the bar chart to sum the data from each row, and to graph 3 bars under those numbers in the Y axis, and the name of what does numbers mean in the X axis. Been searching around and i came off with this, but i feel like its really far away from what i really need.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

arrays = np.loadtxt("D:/uni/txt arkhives/tiempos.txt", dtype=float)
row1 =np.array(arrays[:,0])
row2 =np.array(arrays[:,1])
row3 =np.array(arrays[:,2])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['first', 'second','third'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': row1, 'B': row2, 'C': row3}, index=index)
plt.figure()
df.groupby(['row1','row2','row3']).sum().unstack().plot()
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Graph')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I keep getting this error:

[image: Code Error]

Comment: The txt file is, as i said, just 3 rows of approx. 500 numbers in each row. The idea is to sum all of that and make only 3 numbers that i need to plot.

Comment: It would have been better to post your errors as formatted text instead of as image.

Comment: Thank you : ) Thing is im pretty new into this x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might what you're looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

##If you do not have headers in your file use:
df = pd.read_table("D:/uni/txt arkhives/tiempos.txt",header=None,names = ['A','B','C'])
##If you do have headers in your file use:
df = pd.read_table("D:/uni/txt arkhives/tiempos.txt")

df['bar'] = 1 
dfgroup = df.groupby('bar').sum()
ax = dfgroup [['A','B','C']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Bar Chart", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("X label", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Y Lable", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Make sure the columns names are A, B, C and it should be good.

Comment: Im sorry, but, i dont quite understand how can i bring my txt data to your code. Shall i import it into the code just as i did, then define the df as you said?

Comment: Also, what i need is a simple bar chart with only 3 bars. Each bar is the sum of each column of data

Comment: Yes, this will make the chart you're looking for. try `df = pd.read_table("D:/uni/txt arkhives/tiempos.txt", names = ['A','B','C'])` I've also edited the answer to show where you can insert into your code.

Comment: Which data from your code should i not use? I mean, im a little confused with which parts should i include or which ones should i not. I supposed that the part where i import my data and the part where i define my rows are the ones i take and after that i use your code, but its not working... It throws the error "too many indices for array"

Comment: .I've updated it with read_table example. Depending on the  structure of the .txt file use either the read_table with or without headers and then this code should work for you.